# Chrome extension; How to get all tabs, store tab info to array?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, browser-tab

I would like to take all the windows/tabs from chrome and store the titles/urls to a localstorage array to access later.

I currently have the code below, but it is stopping after the `alert` and returning `"tab is undefined"` and I can't figure it out! Am I completely off base here?

```
function asdf()
{

  chrome.windows.getAll({"populate" : true}, function(windows)

  {

    for(var i = 0; i < windows.length; i++)
    {
      for(var j = 0; j < windows[i].tabs.length; j++)
      {
        original.push(new tabInfo(windows[i].tabs[j], j));
        alert(original[i*j].tab.title);
        original[i*j].tab.title = tab.title;
        original[i*j].tab.url = tab.url;
        original[i*j].tab.status = tab.status;
        original[i*j].count = 0;

        localstorage.setitem["tab.title"];
        localstorage.setitem["tab.url"];
        localstorage.setitem["tab.status"];
       }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect index accessor. Just change original[i*j] to original[original.length - 1].

Answer (score -1):

See also the OneTab extension for doing just that: http://www.one-tab.com/